# Unity for Cities: Skyline mod, Not sure how to make a editable text field

Tags: uitextfield, cities-skylines-api

Summary: have a button to initiate the mod, this brings up a settings screen.
Want to be able to allow the user to enter the Height for the update.
I have not been able to make the field editable, but can display the text field and the values as I want them.

```
    //Calling code
    int top = 1;
    addUILabel(marqueeTerrianPanel, top, Title);
    top += 25;
    ipHeight = addTextField(marqueeTerrianPanel, top, "Height");
   //Procedure to add a textfield
    private UITextField addTextField(UIPanel panel, int yPos, string text)
    {
        UITextField label = panel.AddUIComponent<UITextField>();
        label.relativePosition = new Vector3(1, yPos);
        label.builtinKeyNavigation = true;
        label.height = 20;
        label.width = 80;
        label.text = text;
        label.readOnly = false;
        label.canFocus = true;
        label.isInteractive = true;
        label.enabled = true;
        label.color = Color.white;
        label.bottomColor = Color.white;
        label.textColor = Color.black;
        return label;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution. The differences are mostly the soda and swears, ok the sprites and curser.

```
scaleTextBox.cursorBlinkTime = 0.45f;
scaleTextBox.cursorWidth = 1;
scaleTextBox.selectionSprite = "EmptySprite";
scaleTextBox.normalBgSprite = "TextFieldPanel";
scaleTextBox.hoveredBgSprite = "TextFieldPanelHovered";
scaleTextBox.focusedBgSprite = "TextFieldPanel";
```